# perl: shopping cart - Moose/PSGI

Tags: perl, moose

In the CPAN I found only *shopping cart* solution called *Handel*. It is not bad, but I'm looking for Moose based cart.

Two questions:

1. Is here any Moose-cart package somewhere?
2. Or better, is here any Moose/PSGI/Ajax based web-app for shopping cart solution?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK

1. No.
2. No.

Here are very small amount moose/pgsi applications yet. Unfortunately.